# Ember, Ember-data, and jquery-ui.dialog, "Oh my!"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jquery-dialog

### The task:

Open a form in a lightbox to create a new "event"; the opened form should be bookmarkable.

### The road blocks:

1. There are examples of opening a lightbox using `{{action}}` tags, but could not find one that opened in its own route.
2. There are many examples using older versions of ember.js.
3. There is not a lot of documentation related to ember-data and REST (I know, I know...it isn't "production ready").

### The problem:

The fields in the form were not being tied to a backing model so "null" was being posted to my servlet (a Spring controller).

My very first iteration was not too far off from the [final outcome (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/6thJ4/1/). The thing that finally made it works swapping this:

```
EP.EventsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    ...
    setupController : function(controller, model) {
        controller.set("model", model);
    },
    ...
});
```

...for this:

```
EP.EventsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    ...
    setupController : function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor("events-new").set("model", model);
    },
    ...
});
```

### The question:

Why does the setupController function need to call `controllerFor` in order to properly set up the model?

---

And finally, since I struggled to find a fully-functional example, I wanted to make this accessible (and hopefully discover improvements).

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6thJ4/1/

Here are a few snippets.

### HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div>
        <ul>
            {{#linkTo "events.new" tagName="li"}}
            Add Event
            {{/linkTo}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{outlet events-new}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="events-new">
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>Event Name:</label>
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Host Name:</label>
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="hostName"}}
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

### JavaScript:

```
...
EP.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("events", function() {
        this.route("new");
    });
});
EP.EventsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return EP.Event.createRecord();
    },
    setupController : function(controller, model) {
        //controller.set("model", model); // Doesn't work? Why not?
        this.controllerFor("events-new").set("model", model); // What does this do differently?
    },
    ...
});
EP.EventsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    save : function() {
        this.get("content.transaction").commit(); // "content.store" would commit _everything modified_, we only have one element changed, so only "content.transaction" is necessary.
    }
});
EP.EventsNewView = Ember.View.extend({
...
});
EP.Event = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr("string"),
    hostName : DS.attr("string")
});
```

### Resources:

1. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/
2. http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-all-todos/ (trying to mimic what I learned, but morph the add-new to a new route)
3. [Writing a LightboxView causes problems / Integrating DOM Manipulating jQuery-Plugins makes actions unusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266771/writing-a-lightboxview-causes-problems-integrating-dom-manipulating-jquery-plu) (lightbox "example")
4. [Dependable views in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784973/dependable-views-in-ember) (another lightbox "example" but doesn't have routes for the lightbox opening)

Comment: You may want to clarify the question. You have outlined the background of the question but there doesn't appear to be a direct question in there.

Comment: @Darshan, thanks for the suggestion. I've modified it make the questions pop more.

Please note, there are some context-based questions in the JavaScript snippet as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the setupController function need to call controllerFor in order to properly set up the model?

Ember makes URLs a very integral part of its conventions. This means that the `state` of your application is represented by the route it is on. You've grokked most of this correctly. But there are couple of subtle nuances, that I will clarify below.

First consider an app with the following URLs,

- /posts - shows a list of blog posts.
- /posts/1 - shows a single blog post.

And say clicking on a post in the list at `/posts` takes you to `/posts/1`.

Given this scenario, there 2 ways a user will get to see the post at `/posts/1`.

1. By going to `/posts` and clicking on the 1st post.
2. By typing in `/posts/1`, via bookmarks etc.

In both these cases, the `PostRoute` for `/posts/1` will need the model corresponding to `Post` id 1.

Consider the direct typing scenario first. To provide a way to lookup the id=1 post model, you would use,

```
model: function(params) {
  return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
}
```

Your template for post will get the model and it can render using it's properties.

Now consider the second scenario. Clicking on post with id=1 takes you to `/posts/1`. To do this your template would use `linkTo` like this.

```
{{#linkTo 'post' post}} {{post.title}} {{/linkTo}}
```

Here you are passing in the `post` model to the `linkTo` helper. It then serializes the data for the post into a URL, ie:- '/posts/1'. When you click on this link Ember realizes that it needs to render the `PostRoute` but it already has the post model. So it skips the model hook and directly calls `setupController`.

The default `setupController` is setup to simply assign the model on the controller. It's implemented to do something like,

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
}
```

If you do not need to set custom properties on your controller, you don't need to override it. Note: if you are augmenting it with additional properties you still need to call `_super` to ensure that the default setupController behaviour executes.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  controller.set('customProp', 'foo');
}
```

One final caveat, If you are using `linkTo` and the route does not have `dynamic segments`, then the model hook is still called. This exception makes sense if you consider that you were linking to the `/posts` route. Then the model hook has to fire else Ember has no data to display the route.

Which brings us to the crux of your question. Nearly there, I promise!

In your example you are using `linkTo` to get to the `EventsNewRoute`. Further your `EventsNewRoute` does not have dynamic segments so Ember does call the `model` hook. And `controller.set("model", model);` does work in so much as setting the model on the `controller`.

The issue is to do with your use of `renderTemplate`. When you use `render` or `{{render}}` helper inside a template, you are effectively getting a different controller to the one you are using. This controller is different from the one you set the `model` on, hence the bug.

A workaround is to pass the controller in the options, which is why `renderTemplate` gets this controller as an argument.

```
renderTemplate: function(controller) {
  this.render("events-new", {
    outlet : "events-new", controller: controller
  });
}
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGARC/).

Final Note: Unrelated to this question, you are getting the warning,

> WARNING: The immediate parent route ('application') did not render into the main outlet and the default 'into' option ('events') may not be expected

For that you need to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662791/nested-routes-in-ember-js-and-ember-rails/17674040#17674040). Warning, it's another wall of text! :)

Comment: this in-depth response has propelled me forward in my project! Thank you, kindly!